# Can I use newer Java APIs when running older Java programs with a newer JRE

Tags: java, cross-compiling

I have a Java 8 application with I compiled to Java 8 bytecode using Java 17. So `source` and `target` are both Java 8. Why I did this is that there were many improvements in GC algorithms in Java 17. I did a bit of research and I know that I should write in Java 8 (or earlier) syntax if I want to compile to Java 8 bytecode.

Then I noticed I can't use `Map.of()` function since the api is marked `@since 9` and it confused me. I'm not using any newer Java syntax. **Why is it that I can use GC algorithms that come with Java 17 but I can't use standard libraries that come with it?**

Here's how I think It should work:
JRE 17 (which runs my app) already containts all Java 17 standard libraries compiled in Java 17 bytecode. So when JVM encounters `Map.of()` (or any other methods marked with `@since 9+`) it should just run the standard library as usual.

Also, what is the problem with running `Map.of()` specifically?

Comment: The method does not exist in version 8 of Java. So you can't use it with version 8 of Java. Assume you built a new house. Assume that new house has a new stove. Why can't you use that stove in your old house? **Because** it is in the new house.

Comment: But as I said, the methods are already available. Why can't it just use them?

Comment: You explicitly asked for a class which was compatible with Java 1.8, so `javac` refuses to compile code with `Map.of()` in it. Because that `.class` file wouldn't work with a 1.8 JRE.

Comment: Because, even though you are having JDK 17, you are asking the compiler to use the syntax of JDK 8. What JRE is installed on the target system is immaterial at the time of compilation. Compilation has to restrict the API usage of JDK 8 and before as you have specified that source and target. When actually it is deployed in JDK 17, then it runs with all the features of 17 at the JVM level, but your code is still compiled with compatibility with JDK 8. It can run on JRE 8 too.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong above. You can use `javac -source 1.8 -target 1.8` to compile code which uses `Map.of()`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong:  You using the tools from java17 and the code syntax from Java 8. The jre from Java8 does know the format from bytecode but has no implementation for newer tools.

Comment: When you say "I noticed I can't use Map.of() function", what was preventing you from using it?

Comment: @tgdavies Really? but your explanation sounds reasonable. If I target jre 1.8, it should be runnable on 1.8 so it must not have `Map.of`.
For me it just says "cannot find symbol"

Comment: @tgdavies – When I look at the source code for the RTL, I cannot find a marker for methods or classes that restricts that code to a particular version. There is only the `@since` JavaDoc tag, and I doubt that this will be translated somehow to something like `if( version > 1.8 )` or alike. So that pure extensions of classes like `map.of()` will work does not surprises me. But `var` should not work, also pattern matching should not work, when compiling with `-source 1.8`. The `-target 1.8` only controls the binary output.

Comment: Anyway -- you don't want to do this. Your "older Java program which uses Map.of()" is not going to run on a 1.8 JRE, because it won't find that method, so why bother targeting 1.8 in the first place?

Comment: It's this big old project which was running on java 8, we changed the jre to 17 to use the GC algorithms. Changing language level to 17 is another step which we might take in the future. Since the only people running our program are us, I thought why not use features in java 17 if we can.

Comment: Map.of doesn't exist in jdk 1.8 but it is valid. You can compile fine with source/target set for java 1.8. When you try to run it on a 1.8 jvm though, it cannot find the method. How do you think it could have that method available? Also, if you compile code, then run it on a 1.8 jvm, it will use the 1.8 GC. What problem do you think you would have if you change the language level?

Comment: @matt I only run on jre 17 which should find the method. My question was how is it that it can use GC from java 17, but not `Map.of` from it?

Comment: "it just says "cannot find symbol"" -- what is *it*?

Comment: (and I still don't understand why you aren't compiling with source and target 17)

Comment: @ParSal I don't believe it. If you are using JRE 8, then it will use that GC and it will not be able to find the symbol for Map.of, they dont' exist. They're not included in the class file you compile. If you are using JRE 17, then it will use the new GC and it will find the symbol for Map.of.

Comment: Assume I wrote instructions for preparing a recipe with a two burner stove. You have a four burner stove. So you ***can*** do several of the steps at the same time (when you use a four burner stove), but if you use a two burner stove you **can't**. It's the stove that's different. Not the actual recipe. When you run Java 8 bytecode on Java 17 JVM it can use more burners, it understands the recipe (your bytecode). What you can't do is say this recipe is for a two burner stove, start by lighting all four burners.

Comment: Update: I was wrong: as @tgdavies said the code compiles. The culprit in my case was `<maven.compiler.release>` [which does just that](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-release.html#:~:text=The%20%2D%2Drelease%20option%20ensures%20that%20the%20code%20is%20compiled%20following%20the%20rules%20of%20the%20programming%20language%20of%20the%20specified%20release%2C%20and%20that%20generated%20classes%20target%20the%20release%20as%20well%20as%20the%20public%20API%20of%20that%20release)! Based on everything so far, the answer by @matt below seems correct.

Comment: @tgdavies Can it introduce any complications for the existing code? If I have a java 8 source code which is compiled to java 8 using java 17 and is always ran by java 17, I can't think of anything that would go wrong if I change language level to 17.

Comment: Right, "nothing" could go wrong. If you're compiling it with jdk 17 with source and target set. It will still compile without source and target set. Essentially, declaring source and target make jdk 17 work on a subset of code that it works with. I quoted "nothing" because there is always an exception, especially with the audience you reach on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As java updates a couple things change, although it is supposed to remain backwards compatible. ie unless you're using deprecated classes your code should compile and run with a new jdk.

The bytecode changes, but you can make compatible bytecode by telling javac to "target" an older bytecode version.

On top of that the source code changes. For example, lambda expressions. They didn't exist in java 1.6 so you cannot used them and expect to create 1.6 compatible bytecode. You can tell javac that you want to only compile java 1.6 compatible source code and you'll get an error about lambda expressions.

Once you have compatible source code, and compatible bytecode you have a problem with libraries. This is very simple, say I have a library, "mylibrary.jar" and it has a class "MyClass.class". I can compile the code by providing the library, if you want to run that code. *You still need the library*.

`Map.of` is an addition to the standard jdk, so it doesn't exist in 1.8 jdk's. Everything about it is compatible with java 8, so it passes the source and target tests. You just have to provide it when you run the program. Just like you would any other library.